# In Winforms arrange check boxes dynamically, vertically in 3 columns. Make the number of characters of checkbox text increase if I increase the window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I want to add check boxes dynamically and make them divide equally in 3 columns. Have to arrange them in such a manner that the first column should have ABC....(Top to Down(vertically) not horizontal). If I resize the window using mouse the check box text should continue to display more number of characters if available. For example, I have total 100 characters in each checkbox text but initially it is displaying only 50 characters, but if i expand the size of the window proportionally the number of characters also should increase.

Comment: Then ... do so? What is the concrete problem you're struggling with?

Comment: I have used flowlayout panel in which I can do arrangements as I needed, but not able to do the checkbox text increase while increase the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:

You can achieve this by creating a custom control made of a Checkbox with no text and a Label that is set to Fill (Dock property) and to wrap the text.

Advanced solution:

1. Use a Table Layout panel with 3 columns and 1 row
2. Set the check box controls property Dock to Fill, DoubleBuffered to True
3. For every check box handle the paint event and measure the string length based on the cell size and trim the words if the total string length exceeds the cell boundary.

An simple check box draw example is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7ew2xw1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But in table layout panel i cant arrange the check boxes vertically. It'll fill the checkboxes horizontally into the control.